# pd.round returns weird values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

a subset of my data looks as follows:

```
print(test)
                         created_at
29100988  2020-06-01 00:03:49+00:00
29100989  2020-06-01 00:03:42+00:00
29100990  2020-06-01 00:03:41+00:00
29100991  2020-06-01 00:03:37+00:00
29100992  2020-06-01 00:03:36+00:00
29100993  2020-06-01 00:03:36+00:00
29100994  2020-06-01 00:03:31+00:00
29100995  2020-06-01 00:03:17+00:00
29100996  2020-06-01 00:03:17+00:00
29100997  2020-06-01 00:03:12+00:00
```

I now want to round the colums created_at to minutes using the following code:

```
test['created_at_Min'] = pd.to_datetime(test['created_at']).dt.round("1Min")
```

This yields the following result:

```
                         created_at            created_at_Min
29100988  2020-06-01 00:03:49+00:00 2020-06-01 00:04:00+00:00
29100989  2020-06-01 00:03:42+00:00 2020-06-01 00:04:00+00:00
29100990  2020-06-01 00:03:41+00:00 2020-06-01 00:04:00+00:00
29100991  2020-06-01 00:03:37+00:00 2020-06-01 00:04:00+00:00
29100992  2020-06-01 00:03:36+00:00 2020-06-01 00:04:00+00:00
29100993  2020-06-01 00:03:36+00:00 2020-06-01 00:04:00+00:00
29100994  2020-06-01 00:03:31+00:00 2020-06-01 00:04:00+00:00
29100995  2020-06-01 00:03:17+00:00 2020-06-01 00:03:00+00:00
29100996  2020-06-01 00:03:17+00:00 2020-06-01 00:03:00+00:00
29100997  2020-06-01 00:03:12+00:00 2020-06-01 00:03:00+00:00
```

As you see, while the time "00:03:17+00:00" is correctly rounded to "00:03:00+00:00", the timestamp "00:03:31+00:00" is rounded to "00:04:00+00:00". The same problem arises with hours, and i have absolutely no clue what i am doing wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are 60 seconds in a minute.  The "round up" point is 30, not 50.  Your results are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, using `test['created_at_Min'] = pd.to_datetime(test['created_at']).dt.floor("min")` instead works as desired.